# configure Bind to have a custom domain on tumblr

Tags: bind

I got a server that have inherited and use Plesk to configure a bunch of stuff. 
I would like to use a custom domain on Tumblr and for that I need to create a A rule in bind.
So far my attempts have failed.

I have a master zone define in named.conf as follow:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "example.com";
    allow-transfer {
        [SERVER IP ADRESS];
        common-allow-transfer;
    };
};
```

and the zone is defined like that:

```
; *** This file is automatically generated by Plesk ***
    @   IN  SOA ns.example.com.  (
            1277724944  ; Serial
            10800   ; Refresh
            3600    ; Retry
            604800  ; Expire
            300 )   ; Minimum 10800

example.com.      IN NS   ns.example.com.
ns.example.com.       IN A    [SERVER IP ADDRESS]
example.com.      IN A    [SERVER IP ADDRESS]
webmail.example.com.      IN A    [SERVER IP ADDRESS]
mail.example.com.         IN A    [SERVER IP ADDRESS]
asset1.example.com.       IN A    [SERVER IP ADDRESS]
asset2.example.com.       IN A    [SERVER IP ADDRESS]
blog.example.com.         IN A   72.32.231.8
*.example.com.        IN A    [SERVER IP ADDRESS]
*.webmail.example.com.        IN CNAME    example.com.
ftp.example.com.      IN CNAME    example.com.
www.example.com.      IN CNAME    example.com.
example.com.      IN MX  10 mail.example.com.
example.com.      IN TXT  "v=spf1 +a +mx -all"
ns.example.com.         IN NS   ns.example.com.
```

I have the mapping done on Tumblr IP (blog.example.com.         IN A   72.32.231.8)
I think that having th ip in the zone master definition might be one of the problem but I don't really know bind.

And it's a live server so I can't screw too much with it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: I also don't have access to the domain provider (which is register.com) if it has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using this free online tool to help you debug where the problem is.

http://www.howismydns.com/tools.php

In bind9 you could use names or IP addresses to define DNS entries and you can use * wild-card as well so, I can't see the problem in this zone configuration.

Comment: I use dig which should (and does) give me the same results. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: I found the problem. My dns server wasn't used properly and it was register.com dns server that was doing the resolution. anyway it's fixed. Thanks