# Possible to direct naked domain to external IP

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, cname-record, a-record

So I found this post:

[configure Bind to have a custom domain on tumblr](https://serverfault.com/questions/234260/configure-bind-to-have-a-custom-domain-on-tumblr)

and I was trying to ask a related question:

Would it be possible to set up an A record pointing traffic to domain.com to Tumblr and feed.domain.com to the IP address of my choice? In other words, by setting up a naked domain A record to Tumblr's IP, will I inherently lose traffic to feed.domain.com? Can I write another A record for the specific subdomains I want to point to my server?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't lose traffic to feed.domain.com if you setup an A record to Tumblr's IP. You will need to ensure that you have two records, one for the root domain (domain.com) and another for the subdomain (feed.domain.com).

Alternatively, if your feed address is not an IP address (1.2.3.4) but a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name, like myfeed.anotherdomain.com) use a CNAME record instead of an A record.